# How the .NET Controller parse the request body as json format to a object model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Normally, when I create a POST method, I have a request body as below:

```
{
  "title": "A post request title",
  "body": "A longer body... For example, Italy won the EURO 2021.",
  "created": "2021-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
  "updated": "2021-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
}
```

But in the controller, we just have a method signature like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateSomething([FromBody]Article article)
```

The Article Class:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Body {get;set;}
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}
    public DateTime Updated {get;set;}
}
```

I don't know how the .NET Controller parses the JSON format especially the DateTime format into the Article object model in a deeper dive.

Comment: There are about 20 billion articles on the Internet explaining this.

Comment: @lan Kemp, I tried searching with the same title keyword but I couldn't find the right keyword 'Model Binding'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called Model Binding in ASP.NET.

You can get in-depth details in this MSDN article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You can even customize it if need as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The DateTime you provided looks like ISO 8601 format. But ASP.NET Model Binding can be flexible with date formats.